# Breakdown of 運をつく

Tags: meaning, set-phrases

The title of the chapter in my book is:

> まる子　うんをつく

I know that this has something to do with Maruko being lucky but I don't understand precisely what is meant. Does Maruko have the inherent property of being lucky? Does Maruko get lucky as a one-off event? Something else?

つく is one of those unpleasant verbs with a million and one different meanings. Does it have a clear meaning in this case or should I just treat うんをつく as a set phrase?

Comment: I have voted to close my question due to a misreading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mentioning ちびまる子ちゃん, right?

If so, I guess "「まる子ウソをつく」" is correct.
I guess your book is [this](https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8B%E5%AD%90%E3%82%A6%E3%82%BD%E3%82%92%E3%81%A4%E3%81%8F%E3%81%AE%E5%B7%BB-%E3%81%95%E3%81%8F%E3%82%89%E3%82%82%E3%82%82%E3%81%93/dp/452242647X). Is this correct?

Then, it is not "うん" but "うそ".
ウソ{Uso} is similar to "ウン{unn}". These are confusing but different.

ウソ{uso} is 嘘, "lie".
So, it is translated as "Maruko lies".

I am very sorry if you were not mentioning ちびまる子ちゃん and "ウソ".

By the way, I have never seen the word "うんをつく", so I believe it must be a typo if "うん" was written in your book.

Comment: You clearly know your classic literature :-) I'm an idiot. In the back of my mind I knew that I knew a similar phrase. Thanks.